# Swift: Downcasting to Generic Type in Function Failing

Tags: generics, swift, downcast

I have a generic function that takes a value of any object and an in-out parameter with type T. I want to set the in-out parameter to the value of the any object by downcasting the value to type T.

```
func genericFunction<T>(value:AnyObject, inout object:T) {

    if let castedValue = value as? T {
        object = castedValue
    }
}
```

When I call my function, object's value is not set because the downcast fails.

```
var object:String = "oldValue"
var newValue:String = "newValue"

genericFunction(newValue, &object)
println(object) // prints oldValue
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved by changing AnyObject to "Reflectable". Also worked with "Any". String did not actually conform to AnyObject.

```
func genericFunction<T>(value:Any, inout object:T) {
    if let castedValue = value as? T {
        object = castedValue
    }
}
```

edit:
Any is the type I want to use because Reflectable is meant to be used for Reflection and String happened to conform to it.

Comment: This works only if the value is bridgeable to Any. But what if there are only AnyObjects like with ObjC objects (values from NSDictionaries for example)?